# Control for ASP.NET that allows Global Address List (GAL) integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I know I can use `System.DirectoryServices` to roll my own GAL Name/email selector control and I've seen plenty of people explaining the basics of how to do that, but surly someone knows of one that I can download from somewhere. It just seems like a waste to have to remake it when so many people need it.

Something remotely similar to Outlooks GAL Select Names dialog. It could be simpler.

Comment: I'm watching this with great interest. It would be a useful control in so many applications. If you don't find one, I urge you to put the one you invariably have to write yourself on CodeProject or another snippet sharing community.

Comment: Yeah I'll defiantly consider that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to write my own. Its only a User Control which makes it a PITA to reuse since it can't be compiled to just a DLL and inserted into the tool box. I'm going to continue refining it and start working on making a Custom Server control out of it so it is easily reusable. Once I get it as a server control I'll see about sharing it.